# Jmeter-In ultimate threadgroup, in JTL file elapsed time is not populating properly

Tags: jmeter

I have designed a scenario using multiple ultimate threadgroup. Executed the test for one hour. After the completion of test I have observed weird data in JTL file.
Egs: one of the transaction has 8 api calls. At the end of test 4 only executed. That transaction elapse time is showing 30sec but if you sum of the executed api it is around 10sec. I am surprised where is the remaining 20sec.

Answer (score 0):

- `At the end of test 4 only executed` - when you run a JMeter test for the specified duration of the time there is no guarantee that all Samplers will be executed the equal number of times. Test termination signal might be somewhere in the middle and all the samplers which are below won't be run
- It's hard to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing your test plan and the .jtl file, blind shot: double check your [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) configuration, if you have it like this:

  [image]

  JMeter will add the time taken by all [PreProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) into the overall Transaction elapsed time